# WCF configuration for WebHttpBinding(Restful) for supporting both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: wcf, http, rest, https, webhttpbinding

We are using AJAX Cascading dropdown and AutoComplete functionality with Restful WebService Services providing data. With one endpoint(non-secured) eveything was working fine, until we tried same web page with https. Our Webappplication needs to support both. Our of very few articiles/blogs on this issue I found 2 which applies to my requirements.

1. http://blog.abstractlabs.net/2009/02/ajax-wcf-services-and-httphttps.html
2. http://www.mydotnetworld.com/post/2008/10/18/Use-a-WCF-Service-with-HTTP-and-HTTPS-in-C.aspx

I followed same pattern, added 2 endpoints, assuming WCF will pickup appropriate endpoint looking at HTTP or HTTPS protocol. Worked like a charm in my dev machine(XP-IIS5) and 1 Server 2003R2(IIS6), however did work in Production server 2003-IIS6. Website in IIS is exact same(including permission etc).
The error it throws - Error 500(Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]..)

Here's the sample configuration(ignore typos)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SearchServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="SearchService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="SearchServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SearchServiceContract" />
       <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="SearchServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding" contract="SearchServiceContract" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated ?

Thanks
KSS

Answer (score 0):

I'm using almost the same configuration in my service, though my endpoint behavior references `<webHttp />` instead of `<enableWebScript />`. You mentioned your servers are the same, but in any case, have you tried testing SSL traffic elsewhere on the affected server?

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
I haven't used <webHttp /> yet, you think it can make difference ? I will try it anyways today. Affected server's SSL traffic looks good for other functionality.
Otherwise, does anyone see any issue with the approach ?
Is it possible to have your Rest Webservice(webhhtpbinding) work for both http and https at same time with help of some WCF configuration only ? Or I have to do it programmatically(something like figure out whether call is http or https and use appropriate binding) ?